# PHP Self Processing Form with Wait Notice Before Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a PHP form that uses itself to handle the processing. It has basic javascript validation (client side) and if it passes those tests the form submits to itself for PHP validation (server side), etc. Once complete it redirects to a "thank you" page.

The problem is that the form can take sometime to process due to uploading of images and i am trying to show a message to the user to "Wait!" until it's complete. I thought i had it working with javascript based on the help from another SO post, but when fully implemented its not working :-

When I try inline Javascript to show the box "on submit" it gets wiped when the page reloads to process.

When I try PHP, the form processing has to complete before i can return any display "Wait!" function, at which point it redirects anyway.

Am I trying to do something that's impossible or am i missing something silly? Please excuse any incorrect terminology I am on a steep learning curve. I am trying to avoid using a third party library such as jQuery.

I have posted the minimised code below:

```
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
<input name="contact_us" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input name="full_name" type="text" id="qq_full_name" placeholder="Full Name*">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>


<style>
#processing {
display:block;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#processing.hidden { display:none } /* This hides the message by default */

#popup {
width: 300px;
min-height: 160px;
padding:20px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 5px solid #06C;
text-align: center;
color: #202020;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: -100px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

#popup img { 
height:60px; 
width:60px; 
}
</style>
<div id="processing" class="hidden">
 <div id="popup">
    <img width="60" height="60" src="../processing.gif" />
     <h3>Please Wait!</h3>
     <p>The form is processing...</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>

function validate_Contact(evt) {

var error = '';
var wait = document.getElementById("processing");

// Form Fields
var full_name = document.getElementById("qq_full_name");

// ------------ 

// Full Name
if(full_name.value == ""){
    error += '- Please enter your Full Name \n';
}


// ------------

// Show Error Notice
if(error != '') {
    error = 'The form has not been completed correctly, please check the following:\n\n' + error;
    alert(error);
    evt.preventDefault();  // Stop the event

} else {
    wait.classList.remove("hidden"); // Display Processing Message
    //evt.preventDefault();     

}
}



// DOM elements
var contact_form = document.getElementById("contact_form");

// Set Events (the modern, standards-based way)
contact_form.addEventListener("submit", validate_Contact);

</script>
```

I posted this as new question because I couldn't see a way to expand upon my other SO post. My apologies if this is incorrect.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you need to learn AJAX... :)

Comment: I would suggest that you use AJAX so you can add the PHP processing in a separate file. This would allow you to add on screen loading or dialogs easily from your JS.

Comment: _“When I try inline Javascript to show the box "on submit" it gets wiped when the page reloads to process”_ - browsers usually display the “old” page until data for the new one starts arriving. So if your form takes time to process the data, and only send a response afterwards, I am not really sure how what you are describing can actually occur ...

Comment: @ChrisG if i use AJAX will the user not be stuck on the original page? Or will the separate PHP processing redirect override when its finished? I was under the impression I couldn't use AJAX because the redirect would not function.

Comment: @JamesParry If you want control over what the users sees while uploading a file, you need AJAX; you can even show a progress bar to them. When an AJAX request is done, the browser runs the JS code you provided in a callback function. This code can redirect to another resource as easily as `window.location = "index.php?page=done";`

Comment: @ChrisG I take it there will be no fallback for anyone without javascript enabled doing the AJAX approach?

Comment: @JamesParry Given that AJAX is a bunch of JS functions, there will definitely be fallout :) If you want this to work without JS, everything I told you is out the window.